# I tried to train eigenfaces using knn it trained but when test with new image it give me the error in findnearest function

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, knn

I tried to train eigenfaces using knn. It trained but when I test it with new an image it gives me the error in *findnearest* function

> cv2.error: D:\Build\OpenCV\opencv-3.2.0\modules\ml\src\knearest.cpp:325: error: (-215) test_samples.type() == CV_32F && test_samples.cols == samples.cols in function cv::ml::BruteForceImpl::findNearest

That's my function:

```
ret,id,neighbours,dist=knn.findNearest(S,cv2.ml.COL_SAMPLE,7)
```

Comment: it looks like your matrix S is not well defined...

Comment: Thanks fonfonx its working now

Answer (score 0):

it is probably an error in the typing of the variable S. I went through an error equal to that and decided to put the test case inside an array and it works to me.

Comment: And a didn't use the cv2.ml.COL_SAMPLE, it works with just: knn.findNearest(S, 7)